# How do you Record and Playback editing events on a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, events, contenteditable

I'm trying to find a way to write some unit-tests that can be used to write/test new wysiwyg html editors or just the default browser behavior for contenteditable divs.

I want to record the keypresses (perhaps other events too, but keypresses are the most interesting) or just write the events manually and then play them back later on a div. In the end I would use it to simulate little html editing sessions and see if you end up with the expected serialized html.

BUT, I can't get the following to invoke the default browser behaviour:

```
$(mydiv).trigger('keydown', {type: "keydown", keyCode: 13, which: 13});
```

(It doesn't insert a line-break or break up the paragraph or do anything, really.)

I have also tried things like:

```
$(mydiv).trigger('textInput', {type: "textInput", data: 'H', target: mydiv});
```

(Which should have inserted the letter H)

and I even tried to keep the original event objects around and then trigger them like this:

```
$(mydiv).trigger(eventObject);
```

(where eventObject is an actual  key event I got previuosly and then kept around)

Part of the problem is that I don't know what the minimum event object attributes are that I have to keep around and then send back later. (All of it isn't an option because you can't just dump the whole event as JSON due to all the circular references.)

Another part of the problem is I'm not even sure how to properly focus the editable

At a minimum I need to be able to create a new empty div, set contenteditable="true" and then "insert some text", place the cursor in the middle of it and "press enter" by reading and replaying commands from a log of editing events.

---

**Here's why I need it:**

The idea is to write a lot of tiny tests that can be run in any cutting edge browser (I'm only really interested in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and *maybe* IE9) to see where they differ from what's expected. It is for a survey of what the latest browsers do, not for what 10 year old browsers did.

I can then come up with some kind of checklist of where the browsers deviate from each other. This could then be used by anyone that wants to write a new wysiwyg editor, but ideally the "core" of it - the parts that don't contain or care about any interface/chrome - could be written once and shared by them all.

Individual editors handle things like inserting/removing inline elements, linking text, inserting/editing images, inserting lists and tables, changing a p to an h1 and so on. I'm only really interested in the keypress-level editing here.

Some of these tests could also be used similar to the way javascript frameworks do "feature detection" to see which bits of behavior has to be intercepted/patched so that enter and backspace always behaves the same, so that the cursor is always on the correct side of a b tag and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do what you want here, I don't think. Most browsers do not allow script to fully simulate a keypress: you can fire the event but the associated browser behaviour (updating the value of an input, editing the content of a contenteditable element, moving the caret, etc.) will not happen.

Regarding documenting contenteditable in current browsers, there is an ongoing effort by WHATWG to specify various APIs around contenteditable. Currently in the works is a [spec for `execCommand()`](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-March/030930.html) (there are various threads concerning this on the WHATWG mailing list, check the archives). Preceding this was [some research done on current browser behaviour](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-December/024627.html). There's also ongoing work on a [new version of the DOM Range spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html), now incorporating `Selection` as well. For Enter key behaviour in contenteditable elements, see [this thread](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-May/031577.html).

Comment: I just noticed that Aloha Editor already does something like this: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/dev/src/test/unit/editabletests.js So it must be possible. They use jquery.simulate which looks like it is by the jquery ui project.

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but I also don't think I would use execCommand anyway - it has a lot of issues of its own and ultimately you would want to do something that's not covered by it at which point you would have to mess with the html manually and then undo/redo stops working...

Comment: @Le Roux Bodenstein: Notice the comment in the `pressEnter()` function: *"// finally we need to update the aloha selection (which is normally done automatically)"*. Looks to me like the Aloha editor is intercepting Enter keypresses anyway and that function will only be testing their own event handling, not the browser's own Enter key handling.

Comment: @Le Roux Bodenstein: Agreed about `execCommand()`, its usefulness is currently quite limited.

Comment: @Tim Down My reference here is actually Aloha Editor. That works almost exactly like what I want, except I don't like their user interface and in fact for this project I don't want any user interface at all - this should just level the playing field across all the browsers that are already almost doing the right thing and then provide some APIs (mostly to replace things like execCommand and handle undo/redo) so that it is easy to build an interface on top of it. A WYSIWYG editor core that minimally takes care of all the invisible basics.

Comment: @Le Roux Bodenstein: You may be able to strip Aloha of its interface and use that. Not sure what it does about undo/redo.

Comment: @Tim Down I just did some tests and you were right - that still doesn't allow for testig the browser's own Enter handling.